# On Java Generics

Tags: java, class, generics

A class with the following declaration will compile and run, but does it cause anything unnecessary to happen with memory?

`public class Node<T extends Node<T>> extends NodeContainer<T>`

My fear is that it may eventually cause some type of infinite recursion:

Does `Node<T extends Node<T>>` mean `Node<T extends Node<T extends Node<T(...)>>>` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing will happen at all with memory. Since type erasure takes effect, the generic parameter is not considered at runtime except for runtime casts, and is actually erased. The compiler simply ensures that `T` does extend or implement `Node<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve the link Node>?
It doesn't really make sense 
If you are working with nodes (I am assuming there is some sub child thing??)
if so this might be better

```
Node<T> extends NodeContainer<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> child;
}
```